# Add a group to a group with Chef on Windows

Tags: windows, chef

I'm trying to manage a Windows server with chef, and need to create some users, add them to a group, and add that group to another group.

```
user 'test.user' do
    password    'password'
    action      :create
end

group 'TestGroup' do
    action  :create
    members [ 'test.user' ]
    append  true
end

group 'OtherGroup' do          # This is line 43
    action  :create
    members [ 'TestGroup' ]
    append  true
end
```

That results in an error:

> [2015-02-12T09:54:35+00:00] FATAL: ArgumentError: group[OtherGroup] (users::staff line 43) had an error: ArgumentError: A new member could not be added to a local group because the member has the wrong account type.

It's like Chef can't add a group to a group. Adding users to a group is fine.

Oddly it only seems to affect a custom group. I can add to the built in Users and Administrators groups fine.

```
group 'Administrators' do
    action  :modify
    members [ 'TestGroup' ]
    append  true
end
```

I have also tried creating the `OtherGroup` empty first, and then :modifying it, but the same problem happens.

Answer (score 1):

You have not specified which version of Windows Server you are working with, nor the version of Chef - so these are a few assumptions.

From the Chef docs, it does not appear that adding a group as a member of a groups is supported:

> members
>
> Ruby Type: Array
>
> Which users should be set or appended to a group. When more than one group member is identified, the list of members should be an array: `members ['user1', 'user2']`.

From the error message, we can derive that the operation being attempted is adding a local group to another local group.

The Windows API method that Chef is using under the hood states (emphasis mine):

> The NetLocalGroupAddMembers function adds membership of one or more existing user accounts or **global group accounts** to an existing **local group**. The function does not change the membership status of users or global groups that are currently members of the local group.

- source: [NetLocalGroupAddMembers function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370436(v=vs.85).aspx)
- source: [Chef Win32 API Net](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/cb4ee84e418164e8d2e85147efad711a42ff2799/lib/chef/win32/api/net.rb#L222-L231)

There does not appear to be much spec/test coverage for the underlying API calls in Chef - but from the [call to this method](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/cb4ee84e418164e8d2e85147efad711a42ff2799/lib/chef/win32/net.rb#L193-L196) it appears that the intention of adding members to a group is expected to be a Domain User only, not another local group.